# Tietze extension into $ [0,1)$

Tags: general-topology

Prove or disprove that a continuous real valued function on a closed subset of a normal space into $[0,1)$ can be extended to a continuous real valued function on the entire space into $[0,1)$.

---

I guess the above is false, so I'm trying to find a counter example. 
The only thing I found is the whole space should not be compact. If not, the statement is true directly from the Tietze extension.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the normal space $X$, and the closed subset $A$. Let $f\colon A \to [0,1)$ be continuous.

Tietze's theorem yields an extension $F \colon X \to [0,1]$. Let $B = F^{-1}(1)$, and use the normality of $X$ once more.

Namely, again by Tietze's theorem, there is a continuous $G \colon X \to [0,1]$ with $G\lvert_A \equiv 1$ and $G\lvert_B \equiv 0$. Then $\tilde{f}(x) = G(x)\cdot F(x)$ is a continuous extension of $f$ with values in $[0,1)$.

Comment: You mean $g:A\cup  B \rightarrow [0,1)$ s.t. $g(x)=f(x)$ on $x\in A$ can be extended continuously into $[0,1)$?

Comment: Immediately, you again only know that you get an extension with values in $[0,1]$. Think of $g\colon A \cup B \to [0,1]$ given by $$g(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &, x \in A \\ 0 &, x \in B.\end{cases}$$

Comment: I only understand that $g$ can be continuously extended to $G:X\rightarrow [0,1] $ which is a (surjective) bump function. Can you give me more explanation?

Comment: I've edited the answer. Point is: $G\cdot F$.

Comment: Oh I see, I got confused, thank you.